# mysql - query to fill in missing datetime values

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a Table similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
    `stat_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `stat_Start` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stat_values` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`stat_ID`),
    );
```

It contains a list of events with the time it happenned, and the value.

I am now looking to generate a report from this similar to:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(stat_start,16) AS `time`,
    AVG(`stat_values`) AS `data` 
FROM stats s 
WHERE s.stat_Start BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY LEFT(s.stat_start,16) 
ORDER BY stat_start;
```

In other words, get the `Average` value for all entries per minute for the past hour.

However, in some cases I don't have an entry for some minutes, but I still need to know that there were 0 results for that minute. 
Is there a way of achieving this in MySQL?

so I might get something like:

```
'2017-04-07 09:01', 102,
'2017-04-07 09:02', 0, --> row for which no events were recorded
'2017-04-07 09:03', 132
```

Comment: The same problem answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533485/aggregating-data-by-date-in-a-date-range-without-date-gaps-in-result-set

Answer (score 0):

Filling in 'missing' rows is done via an extra table with all possible values, plus a `LEFT JOIN`:

Create have a table `all_minutes` with all possible minutes (in some finite range).  (If using MariaDB, use a "Sequence" table.)  Then

```
SELECT a.time,
       IFNULL(s.data, 0)  AS `data`  -- assuming you want 0, not NULL
    FROM all_minutes AS a
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
            LEFT(stat_start,16) AS `time`,  -- eg, '2017-04-07 11:03'
            AVG(`stat_values`) AS `data` 
        FROM stats
        WHERE stat_Start BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND NOW()
        GROUP BY `time`
        ORDER BY `time`    -- note a change here
              ) AS s    ON s.time = a.time
    WHERE a.time BETWEEN ... AND ...; -- whatever range you need
```

Note:  Both tables should exclude or include the `:00` for seconds.  Otherwise (I think) there could be some difficulty in doing the `=` in the `ON`.